# Help creating Visualforce Page for custom Help links

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, customer-community, helptext

Developed externally hosted online help for which we will be using the "Help for this page" links on Salesforce objects.

We are considering moving the help to fully within Salesforce and investigating our options to do so.
We haven't created any VF pages yet, as we're still trying to determine options.

Is there anything that can be suggested for the best implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the entire Visualforce route and could create the help pages in pure HTML with CSS, etc in a file structure in a static resource.
The performance would be faster, and the pages wouldn't add all those items to the VF page list. Link to the proper page in the static resources, and then use relative links to include CSS, JS, etc. All encapsulated in one static resource.

Comment: Estimated about $20,000 to do the work, which seems high to me